# Display the Alternative columns from table row

Tags: oracle, unpivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksDNA.jpg)

Display the Alternative columns from table row

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `salary` column to a string data type (so that `salary` and `name` have the same data type) and then `UNPIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, name, salary ) AS
 SELECT 100, 'A', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 101, 'B', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 102, 'C', 3000 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id, value
FROM   (
  SELECT id, name, TO_CHAR( salary ) AS salary
  FROM   test_data
)
UNPIVOT ( value FOR key IN ( name, salary ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
>  ID | VALUE
> --: | :----
> 100 | A    
> 100 | 1000 
> 101 | B    
> 101 | 2000 
> 102 | C    
> 102 | 3000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa78d5fe2fedc994e03e9d19cdf0ed9b)*

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, UNION ALL can also work for you, If you agreed to change the datatype of Salary column -

```
SELECT ID, Name "Name & Salary"
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Salary
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY ID, Name
```